# Solving closed loop function with constant K in matlab

Tags: function, matlab

[image]

So im trying to solve the closed loop function: Y(s)/U(s).
But whats putting me off is the constant 'k'. I want to equation to be solved including the constant k but matlab keeps coming with an error saying k is unknown function. How do I include a constant in the equation when solving closed loop function?

Normally I would solve the equation by doing:

```
G1 = tf([k], [1, 7, 15, 13, 4]); 
sys1 = feedback(G1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish what you are trying to do, it is necessary that you have the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic.html), since *k* is an unknown constant and, therefore, needs to be a symbolic variable in Matlab.

It seems that you are using the Control System Toolbox. Since it [does not support symbolic variables](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/360264-how-can-i-work-on-simulink-with-symbolic-representation-variable#answer_284797), you can still perform the calculation, but you cannot use the `tf` and `feedback` functions for that. One suggestion would be as follows:

```matlab
syms k s G1 sys1                    % 'syms' creates symbolic variables
G1 = k / poly2sym([1 7 15 13 4],s)  % 'poly2sym' creates a symbolic polynomial from the 
sys1 = simplify(G1 / (1 + G1*1))    %            vector of coefficients
```